# Calculating a fixed average of a measure so that I can compare it to an individuals number

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, measure

I am trying to create a fixed average for all employees from my measure column so that i can compare it to an individuals own score. This in a dax power bi report

I have the following table craeted in power bi [image: Table]

This shows the employee and a number of statistics relating to them.

The column Overall AVG Prod Moves Per LO Hour =
`CALCULATE(SUM('Base Data'[Moves])/SUM('Base Data'[TimeROSDeployed[H]]]))`

When i put it into a graph and use the built in average function, it returns me an average of 12.25
[image: graph]

I have a number of filters applied such as shiftdate, moves and timedeployed.

I want to create a fixed average measure / number from this so that I can compare an individuals score against this on another page so that if i select an employee id, it shows their average using the current measure and a fixed average that isnt affected by the employeeid filter (but remains affected by other filters)

I have tried this a variety of ways and gotten nowhere, the closest I have managed to get is to return the correct value when no employee is selected using the following code

```
ADDCOLUMNS( 
SUMMARIZE( 
ALLSELECTED('Base Data'[Employee]), 'Base Data'[Employee])
, "@avgpmlo", calculate('Base Data'[Overall AVG Prod Moves Per LO Hour]))
, [@avgpmlo])
```

How would I then apply the calculate function to get the value to stay static
[image]
[image]

Comment: There comes a time in everyone's Power BI journey where you have to learn about the mighty, mighty CALCULATE function, which lets you selectivly remove filters from the filter context in a measure.  Start here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculate-in-dax/

Comment: I have tried this a variety of ways and gotten nowhere, the closest I have managed to get is to return the correct value when no employee is selected using the following code
``` PROD MOVES = 
    AVERAGEX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            ALLSELECTED('Base Data'[Employee]), 'Base Data'[Employee]),
            "@avgpmlo", calculate('Base Data'[Overall AVG Prod Moves Per LO Hour])),
            [@avgpmlo])```

How would I then apply the calculate function to get the value to stay static

I have edited the question with new pictures etc to verify

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
AverageHoursAllEmployee = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('EmployeeHours'[Hours]), all('EmployeeHours'[EmployeeId]))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as I can not select my measure Overall AVG Prod Moves Per LO Hour
-----------------------------
The second part i entered into the original question with the picture gets what i desire with no filters applied but as mentioned, when i put an employee filter on, it calculates for that employee ``` ADDCOLUMNS( 
SUMMARIZE( 
ALLSELECTED('Base Data'[Employee]), 'Base Data'[Employee])
, "@avgpmlo", calculate('Base Data'[Overall AVG Prod Moves Per LO Hour]))
, [@avgpmlo])  ```